# How to link multiple mach-o files with terminal on MacOS

Tags: macos, dyld, mach-o

I created two files: a.c and b.c, they are both *.c file;

Then I use terminal to compile both with command:

```
gcc -c a.c
gcc -c b.c
```

I got two mach-o files: a.o and b.o;

So what can I do to link them and generate a linked object file like ab.o ?

I tried the following:

```
ld a.o b.o -e main -o ab
```

But it turned me down with the following:

```
ld: warning: No version-min specified on command line
ld: dynamic main executables must link with libSystem.dylib for inferred architecture x86_64
```

So what should be done next ?

Comment: Do you want a "linked object file like ab.o" or do you want an executable? Your example command line looks like you're trying to link an executable (you specify a main function and the output name doesn't have a ".o" suffix). To make a linked object file, you can use `ld -r -o ab.o a.o b.o`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just feed them back to `gcc`:

```
gcc -o ab a.o b.o
```

Side note: you might wanna call the resulting file `ab.out` or `ab` without suffix, but probably not `ab.o`, since that usually implies an *unlinked* object file.

Comment: It's possible to take two object files and combine them into one, where references between them are resolved. That's what I guessed OP was looking for and what the command in my comment would accomplish but, admittedly, it's not completely clear.

Comment: Thanks, and also I found I could use clang as well.

Comment: @Boris Well depending on your setup (particularly if you have NOT installed any custom `gcc`), on macOS/with Xcode `gcc` is actually just `clang`. You can check whether that's the case with `gcc -v`.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtspQ.png)

why link a.o and b.o  to  ab  ,but  a.o and b.o  text size is not ab.o  text size

0000005c != 0000002e + 0000002c

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).